# javascriptの時間表示を変えたい

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

現在reactでコードを書いています。
axiosでもらってきたjson形式のデータを表示させています。
ここの画像で2020-03-18までを表示させたいのですがjsonの情報自体に時間も含まれているのでどう表示させたらいいかわかりません。javascriptのgetmonthなど試してみたのですが上手く表示されなかったため、どなたか教えていただけますでしょうか。

```
<TableCell >日にち</TableCell>      
{
    Payments.map((transaction, index) => (
        <TableCell>{transaction.CreatedAt}</TableCell>
}
```

[image: ここの日にちの表示]

Answer (score 1):

Dateインスタンスに変換後、好きなフォーマットに文字列化してはどうですか？

```js
const date = new Date( '2020-03-18T06:10:17Z' );
console.log(`${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth() + 1}-${date.getDate()}`); // 2020-3-18
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！時間の取得はしてないですが時間まで出ている形です。このような形になりました。2020/03/18 15:10